# Is possible use JTree in Eclipse plugin development instead of standard JFace tree?

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, jface, jtree

Is possible use JTree in Eclipse plugin development instead of standard JFace tree?

I'm developing it in Kepler, wan't work with custom icons etc. like in JTree.

Comment: You can embed `JTable` in SWT but don't know about `JTree`. Look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)

Comment: JFace trees can use custom images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JTree and other Swing controls using [SWT_AWT bridge](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_embed_AWT_and_Swing_inside_SWT?). However, this is far from trivial, as Swing will have its own event loop, you'll have to figure out which UI thread different code should run on, translate between different types of events (e.g. when resizing) etc. Generally it's better to figure out how to achieve your purposes in the SWT/JFace/RCP way.

Comment: Well there's a problem that I have library which do some simulation and use JTree and have to implement it as plugin to Eclipse.

Comment: In that case, sure, try using SWT_AWT first and see if it's suitable.